# Very basic question: what is an accepted term for "linear order distance"

Tags: distance, manhattan

In data science we have "Manhattan Distance" as a slang term for *Level 1 Distance* and "Euclidean Distance" as a slang term for *Level 2 Distance*. Is there an accepted term for linear distance in memory of cells in different rows in a matrix? That is, given an 8x8 matrix, the "linear distance" from [3,2] to [4,5] is:
(4-3) * 8 + (5-2)

This is the distance in memory addressing. "Level 0 Distance" doesn't really work as a technical term, because computer memory layout is not a native concept in mathematics. Is there a standard term for this? It reminds me of the old flyback transformers in cathode ray tubes, so "flyback distance" makes sense as a slang term.

Comment: This doesn't strike me as common enough to have a standard name, though I've also never heard "Level i Distance" before, so maybe I'm just coming from the wrong field. I'd suggest also "reading distance" as being evocative of the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is the Manhattan / $L_1$ / Norm 1 distance, if you just multiply the row by $8$ (or $N$).

The $L_1$ distance between $[24, 2]$ and $[32, 5]$ is what you are looking for.

Comment: Right, it's the L1 distance of the matrix linearized. But that linearization is not a mathematical concept, it is just an implementation detail. I'm searching for some reason to not just fabricate my own word, "flyback", for this distance.

Comment: I think this is different: AIUI, the OP's distance from [3,5] to [4,2] is 5, not 11.